# Transistion from clockwise to counter-clockwise modes smoothly using WPF storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard

**Edit: The project can be downloaded from [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=95D1BB2065E34E8A!3572&authkey=!AIaFLR5V4S6i4ho).**

I am using WPF Storyboard to animate the Earth rotation, and I want to be able to reverse the rotation from clockwise to counter-clockwise (and vice versa) when user clicks a button, although in reality this should never happen.

[image]

In my XAML file, I declare 21 BitmapImages (the first and the last are identical) and 2 Storyboards, one for clockwisely rotation and the other for counter-clockwisely rotation.

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowWPF.StoryboardSeekWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="StoryboardSeekWindow" Height="400" Width="400">
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage0" UriSource="Images\rotation\0.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage1" UriSource="Images\rotation\1.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage2" UriSource="Images\rotation\2.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage3" UriSource="Images\rotation\3.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage4" UriSource="Images\rotation\4.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage5" UriSource="Images\rotation\5.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage6" UriSource="Images\rotation\6.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage7" UriSource="Images\rotation\7.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage8" UriSource="Images\rotation\8.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage9" UriSource="Images\rotation\9.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage10" UriSource="Images\rotation\10.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage11" UriSource="Images\rotation\11.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage12" UriSource="Images\rotation\12.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage13" UriSource="Images\rotation\13.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage14" UriSource="Images\rotation\14.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage15" UriSource="Images\rotation\15.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage16" UriSource="Images\rotation\16.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage17" UriSource="Images\rotation\17.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage18" UriSource="Images\rotation\18.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage19" UriSource="Images\rotation\19.png"/>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage20" UriSource="Images\rotation\20.png"/>
    <Storyboard x:Key="clockwiseStoryboard" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="imgRotatingEarth" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage0}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage1}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage2}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage3}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage4}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.0" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage5}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage6}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.4" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage7}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.6" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage8}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.8" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage9}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.0" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage10}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.2" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage11}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.4" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage12}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.6" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage13}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.8" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage14}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.0" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage15}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.2" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage16}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.4" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage17}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.6" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage18}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.8" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage19}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4.0" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage20}}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="counterClockwiseStoryboard" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="imgRotatingEarth" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage20}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage19}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage18}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage17}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage16}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.0" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage15}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage14}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.4" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage13}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.6" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage12}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.8" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage11}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.0" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage10}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.2" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage9}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.4" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage8}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.6" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage7}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.8" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage6}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.0" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage5}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.2" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage4}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.4" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage3}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.6" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage2}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.8" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage1}}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4.0" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource RotationImage0}}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="imgRotatingEarth" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="50" Stretch="Uniform" />

    <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Reverse" Height="30" Width="100" Click="reverseButton_Click" />
</Grid>
```

and my code behind file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace StackOverflowWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for StoryboardSeekWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class StoryboardSeekWindow : Window
    {
        Storyboard clockwiseStoryboard;
        Storyboard counterClockwiseStoryboard;
        bool bRotateClockwisely;
        TimeSpan duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4);
        double dProgress = 0; //the value of dProgress is from 0.0 (begin) to 1.0 (end)

        public StoryboardSeekWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            clockwiseStoryboard = this.FindResource("clockwiseStoryboard") as Storyboard;
            counterClockwiseStoryboard = this.FindResource("counterClockwiseStoryboard") as Storyboard;
            StartRotation();
        }

        private void StartRotation()
        {
            counterClockwiseStoryboard.Begin();
            counterClockwiseStoryboard.Pause();

            clockwiseStoryboard.Begin();

            bRotateClockwisely = true;
        }

        private void reverseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Storyboard sbActive = bRotateClockwisely ? clockwiseStoryboard : counterClockwiseStoryboard;
            Storyboard sbPaused = bRotateClockwisely ? counterClockwiseStoryboard : clockwiseStoryboard;

            sbActive.Pause();

            //I want the other storyboard can seek to where the animation is paused.
            dProgress = sbActive.GetCurrentProgress();
            dProgress = 1.0 - dProgress;
            sbPaused.Seek(new TimeSpan((long)(duration.Ticks * dProgress)));

            sbPaused.Resume();

            bRotateClockwisely = !bRotateClockwisely;            
        }
    }
}
```

In order to get a smooth transition from clockwise to counter-clockwise mode, I pause the active animation and calculate which frame I am in, when resume the reverse animation, I first seek to that frame. In order words, I want to achieve the effect.

0.png->1.png->2.png->3.png->4.png->5.png->**user clicks button**->5.png->4.png->3.png->2.png->1.png->0.png->...

But my code does not work. The Storyboard.Seek() seems to be working, but it does not start rotating reversely. I think I might be wrong in running 2 storyboards to manipulate the same object.

Could someone help me to fix the bugs, and perhaps provide a better idea to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed my own problem:

The reversing animation will not be fired if the current Storyboard is not **stopped**. So instead of pausing the current Storyboard and resuming the reversing Storyboard, I should stop the current Storyboard and start the reversing Storyboard.

And the Storyboard.Seek() should be called **after** it has began. The Seek() method has no effect if a Storyboard has not began.

This is how the code looks like now.

```
private void reverseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard sbActive = bRotateClockwisely ? clockwiseStoryboard : counterClockwiseStoryboard;
    Storyboard sbPaused = bRotateClockwisely ? counterClockwiseStoryboard : clockwiseStoryboard;


    //I want the other storyboard can seek to where the animation is paused.
    dProgress = sbActive.GetCurrentProgress();
    dProgress = 1.0 - dProgress;

    sbActive.Stop();           

    sbPaused.Begin();
    sbPaused.Seek(new TimeSpan((long)(duration.Ticks * dProgress)), TimeSeekOrigin.BeginTime);

    bRotateClockwisely = !bRotateClockwisely;            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You *might* be 'barking up the wrong tree' here with all those images... how about trying something like this instead?:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="RotationImage0" UriSource="Images\rotation\0.png">
    <BitmapImage.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="RotateTransform" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" Angle="0" />
    </BitmapImage.RenderTransform>
</BitmapImage>
<BitmapImage.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLoading, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Control.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ReverseRotationStoryboard" />
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="RotationStoryboard">
                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.
(RotateTransform.Angle)" From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:2.0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="RotationStoryboard" />
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="ReverseRotationStoryboard">
                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.
(RotateTransform.Angle)" From="360" To="0" Duration="0:0:2.0" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</BitmapImage.Style>
```

If you require distinct 'steps' in your animation, you could replace the `DoubleAnimation` above with the following:

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.
(RotateTransform.Angle)" Duration="0:0:0.9">
    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0" />
    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="30" KeyTime="0:0:0.075" />
    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="60" KeyTime="0:0:0.150" />
    ...
    <DiscreteDoubleKeyFrame Value="330" KeyTime="0:0:0.825" />
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

This basically works by binding to a `Boolean` property called `IsLoading` (adapted from my program). You can call your property whatever you like, but the idea is to set it to `false` to reverse the direction of the `Animation`. I trust that you will be able to set this property dependent on the user's `Click`.

Notice the `Storyboard` in the `DataTrigger.EnterActions` section... this occurs as the property 'becomes' `true`. Now look at the `Storyboard` in the `DataTrigger.ExitActions` section... this occurs when the property ceases to be `true`, or 'becomes' `false`.

Comment: It is not the Earth as seen from above the North Pole, so the animation can't be done by using RotateTransform on a single image. And your code has the same problem as I am facig, when you property toggles between 'true' and 'false', the angle will be set to 360 or 0 (that is the angle at the start of the rotation) before it reverses rotation direction, right?